# Slack-send message with notification but without popup

Tags: slack

I chat with my boss through slack, he is always in meetings and so his screen is always shared with clients, so when I send a message, it will popup during a meeting and so it can be seen buy other persons.
This is OK most of the time, I don't care my professional messages being seen by others, but sometimes I want to tell him something more private and in that case I don't expect any popup.

Is there a way to send a message without popup? but just case by case, not always. It should not be silent, there must be the small red icon notification but no popup.

Any idea?

Comment: I need this too!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, send a message with minimal words for which you don't care, you collegue will get a popup, right after edit the message. The update does not popup